# Application, installed using setup project cannot take access to folder

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project, file-access

I have .net application, when it is compiled everything is ok. It saves an image file to its folder. When I use `Ctrl+F5` in Visual Stuio, or when I copy exe-file to some folder, it is ok. But, when I make setup project I have an `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`, on line `image.Save(....);`. How to get access for my application?

Comment: Try running application as an administrator or after disabling UAC. Applications are not allowed to save files in Operating System Directory in Windows 7. Ideally you should save the image in AppData folder

Comment: Running as administrator works. What to do to make shortcut opening as administrator?

Comment: Don't save image in operating system directory. Save it in Application Data Folder.